# Initialising char** in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I looked at most of related posts but unfortunately I couldn't get a satisfactory answer for my concrete case.

I am using a 3rd party library which has a structure with an attribute of `char**`, which I need to populate. I tried almost everything imaginable that I thought would be valid c++ syntax and would work, however I always get a run-time error trying to assign it.

*To clarify I should say that the array of strings should take (i assume) names of files.*

Consider this as our code:

`char** listOfNames; // belongs to the 3rd party lib - cannot change it
    listOfNames =       // ???`

So my question is how to initialize this variable with one or more string file names, eg: "myfile.txt" ?

*Should also be c++11 compatible.*

Comment: What are you trying to fill it with? What have you tried?

Comment: And what are you asking for? Do I get you wrong or is your question "What does `char **` mean?"? And If you explicitly ask about c++ why tagging C? Also I would bet, the bahving of `char **` won't be different in c++11 ^^

Comment: I get a different warning when using c++11 than when compiling on c++

Comment: Have you figured out what this char** is used for? Setting it to NULL should be valid C++, but isn't likely to help you.

Comment: Then give us the code, you are geting the warning with. as the presented code will not just get a warning, it won't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should initialize the `listOfNames` as a dynamic string array and then initialize each element of the array as the following codes:

```
char** listOfNames; // belongs to the 3rd party lib - cannot change it

int iNames = 2; // Number of names you need

try
{
    // Create listOfNames as dynamic string array
    listOfNames = new char*[iNames];

    // Then initialize each element of the array
    // Element index must be less than iNames
    listOfNames[0] = "Hello";
    listOfNames[1] = "World";
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

Comment: That code works perfectly, that is what i was looking for. Just one more thing: on the lines where you assign the actual values, you need to explicitly cast to char \*, otherwise you get a warning (deprecated conversion on cpp0x and "iso c++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to char*" in c++11 )... Cheers!

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: Thanks for telling me about the conversion warning.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Keep in mind that although string literals have static storage duration throughout the program lifetime, they are *not* modifiable. Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined behaviour*. That is why most compilers warn when you assign the address of a string literal to a non-const pointer to `char`. Doing `listOfNames[0][0] = 'J'` is thus UB.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
char** listOfNames; // belongs to the 3rd party lib - cannot change it
try
{
    listOfNames = new char*[10] { "Hello", "world", ... };
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{
    // delete the arrays here...
    // ...
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

?

Comment: Don't forget to check for failure of new and to free the memory when you no longer need it.

Comment: Of course :).
We have to check if the allocation failed (for example by using a try / catch block to see if it throws a std::bac_alloc).

Comment: I actually get a syntax error on that code (without the dots).  
listOfNames = new char*[10] { "Hello", "world"};      // i get Expected ';' after expression

Comment: Can we se the rest of your code? I don't have any error here.

Comment: i created a new dummy project just for the case so mine is literally just this:
int main()
{
    char ** asd;
    asd = new char*[10] {"Hello", "world"};
}

Comment: Before someone asks: [Compiler] Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)    [IDE] Xcode 6.1

Comment: I some cases, Clang seems to have a "strange" behavior on Mac. Maybe that's because we pass only 2 strings to the initializer list of an array with length 10?

Comment: doesn't seem to be the problem, i tried with more and less but the same issue remains... ; \

Comment: Actually, i found that on my compiler that doesn't compile only as c++98 otherwise it does as c++11 and c++14... then it's only complaint is a warning to do with the implicit casts (from string literal to char*). Cheers, for the effort.